# My regex function seems to be right but it doesn't work

Tags: php, regex

I'm trying to remove a script that contains a malware from my database.
 
It was injected in a lot of registers of my table.
The script starts with a `<script>` tag and ends with a `</script>` tag.
I'm using the following code to find and replace it:

```
$content = $post->post_content;
$new_content = preg_replace('/(<script>.+?)+(<\/script>)/i', '', $content);
```

I've tested it on regx101.com and it's working fine but on my code, it doesn't work.
Does anyone know what's wrong?

Comment: You should *never* parse HTML with regex. Use [a PHP DOM parser](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/) instead.

Comment: `.` does not extend to new lines unless `s` modifier is used. You should not use regex for HTML though. Your groupings and the `+` on the opening script also are a bit strange.

Comment: "Now you have two problems."

Answer (score 0):

Here is my goto regex for `<script>...</script>` tags with their contents:

```
(\<script\>)([\s\S]*?)(<\/script>)
```

You're not escaping some key characters and you're not capturing everything which could be in the contents of the tags.

Here is an explanation of the content capturing group:

`\s` matches any whitespace character
 
`\S` matches any non-whitespace character
 
`*?` matches between zero and unlimited times, as few times as possible, expanding as needed

As I stated before, you really shouldn't do this. You should use [a PHP DOM parser](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/) instead.